# .asp?openurl=xxx. How i can get "xxx"

Tags: asp-classic, openurl

my single index.asp site like this

```
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="0,*,0" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO" border="0">
<frame src="123456789" name="mainFrame">
</frameset>
</html>
```

when i go address index.asp?openurl=www.google.com

How www.google.com is import to 123456789

Comment: BTW, this is "Classic" ASP, not ASP.NET. It's quite outdated, in case you didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<frame src="http://<%=Request.Querystring("openurl")%>" name="mainFrame">
```

Note that if you're using an absolute url as an src value you need to enter the `http://` bit.  You can either do it the way I have or you can include it in your querystring value.